# How to add arp addresses into /proc/net/arp in C

Tags: c, linux, arp

I would like to add arp bindings into `/proc/net/arp` in `C`. Writing into file is not allowed, so trying to do it some other way. Any suggestions? I already know about net-tools, but havent tryed yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ip neigh add can do this:

For example:

```
root@refactor:~# ip neigh show
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:1b:da:29:3a:87 REACHABLE
root@refactor:~# ip neigh add 192.168.1.2 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:1b:da:29:3a:89
root@refactor:~# ip neigh show
192.168.1.2 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:1b:da:29:3a:89 PERMANENT
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:1b:da:29:3a:87 REACHABLE
```

Is this what you want to do?

If you want to do this directly in C, look at the source of the `ip` tool, which is part of the `iproute2` package.

Comment: thanks man, but i want to do it directly in C. thanks for the hint

Comment: Rather than looking at the source, run `strace ip ...`

Comment: ltrace is even better, it tells you the higher level API it used.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [netlink protocol](http://sdepl.ucsd.edu/cgi-bin/yman2html?m=netlink&s=7#NETLINK_ARPD) or [libnetlink](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/libnetlink.htm). I would recommend looking at the source for the `arp` command to see exactly how it does it.